# In Access VBA, would it be possible to set the subform source object to a query but without the query. as a prefix?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access VBA, when I set the subform source object to a query in VBA, it must use "Query.myQuery", but the issue is that when a user's Access is in different language like Chinese, then this will not work, becuaes the source object name will be interpreted as "查询.myQuery", and Access will fail to execute. I wonder if there is a way that in VBA only need to set the subform source object to "myQuery", thus if the user's Access in different language, the program stil can work.

Answer (score 1):

Use a form you have set to view as *DatasheetView* as the subform.

Set the *RecordSource* of the subform to your query.